# CakePHP mkdir does not work on production server

Tags: cakephp

I have the following code setup for my `admin_add` in my `photocategories_controller.php` file. This code works great in my CentOS development server at home. However, it does not work when I upload this file to my production server. Any help will be appreciated~

```
function admin_add() {
    .... //Other code here

    //On folder add, get its ID to be used as the name of the folder
    $folderID = $this->Photocategory->getLastInsertId();

    //This directory is already created
    $uploadDir = '/img/uploads/photos/';
    $serverRoot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

    //Folder location to be created. When I print it I get
    // /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/img/uploads/photos/16 === 16 being the last inserted ID
    $directoryPath = $serverRoot.$uploadDir.$folderID;

    //I CANNOT FIGURE OUT WHAT AM I DOING WRONG HERE. IT WORKS IN MY DEVELOPMENT
    //SERVER, BUT NOT IN MY PRODUCTION SERVER       
    if(mkdir($directoryPath, 0777)){
        if(mkdir($directoryPath."/thumb", 0777)){
            $this->Session->setFlash('Success', 'default', array('class' => 'alert_success'));
        }else{
            $this->Session->setFlash('Error creating thumb', 'default', array('class' => 'alert_error'));
        }
    }else{
        $this->Session->setFlash('Error Creating Directory', 'default', array('class' => 'alert_error'));
    }
```

Comment: Wild guess: permission issue. Propably your www-data isn't allowed to write in this folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED! I am not sure why, but my production server was not detecting my server root as I expected it to. It was seeing `$serverRoot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` as the `public_html` folder. However I needed the `webroot` folder. So I used CakePHP's own `WWW_ROOT`.

Answer (score 0):

For this it is useful to use the API function cakephp Folder, making the creation of directory more safe and controlled

more information here

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/file-folder.html